# Cant access model data in my viewcontroller

Tags: swift

Trying to access the array of structs for my main controller. It doesn't work though? Any guesses why? 
Note: `DeckOfCards` is an enum and decks is an array of structs.

```
// Model.swift
class Model {

    var decks:[DeckOfCards]
    init(decks:[DeckOfCards]) {

        self.decks = decks
        decks = [DeckOfCards(cardDigit: 0), DeckOfCards(cardDigit: 1), DeckOfCards(cardDigit: 2)
    }

}

/* This is a class variable allowing me to access it without first instantiating the model. Now we can retrieve the model without instantiating it directly

var model = Model.sharedInstance
*/
class var sharedInstance: Model {
    if !(Static.instance != nil) {
        Static.instance = Model()   <---ERROR, missing parameter decks in call
    }
    return Static.instance!
}
```

controller file (not working)

```
var thiscard = Model.sharedInstance.decks
```

Following `println` doesnt work

```
println(thiscard.decks.count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model accepts `decks` but you are not passing any when you create a new instance of `Model`.

Comment: like this? var acard = thiscard(cardDigit: 4)

Comment: Not sure, what you want to achieve with your code but Static.instance = Model(decks: []) should be enough.

Comment: this piece of code: " Static.instance = Model()" is givig the error, missing parameter 'decks' in call

Comment: Yeah, use the line I gave you.